# How to minimally use Babel to use "import {obj1, obj2} from 'my-location'" in Node - without NPM

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I am new to NodeJS and have decided to go the route of writing "vanilla Node" to stay close to core and reduce dependencies.  As it is right now, I have Node `v10.16.2` installed globally on my MacBook, and all I need is a folder with a file like `index.js` and can do most of what I need.

Although `require('./some-app')` works fine, I quickly see that being able to cherry pick from a module is desirable.  But `import {someobject, somevar, etc} from './some-app'` doesn't natively work in Node.

Is there a very simple way to

1. transpile one-for-one all files I create from a `src` to a `dist` folder and
2. optionally, watch and update the `dist` folder while I make changes to a `src` file?

Answer (score 0):

Node has experimental support for ES6 modules
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

You'll have to call node with the flag, i.e.

```
node --experimental-modules [blah blah]
```

Comment: I made progress but not to finish line.  I upgraded to 12.9.1 using `brew upgrade node`.  my source file has `import './app.js` which no longer gives an exception.  HOWEVER, app.js only has a test line `var test='es6'` - and when I do console.log(test) in the main file, it says `test is not defined`.  What is wrong on my syntax in app.js or the import line? Appreciate your help